# How to apply a function to every consecutive n elements in a vector

Tags: r

I am trying to convert quarterly returns to yearly returns. Given a vector of quarterly returns, how can this be done?

I am fairly new to R-programming, so I haven't really gotten anywhere.

Given a vector `a` that contains quarterly returns:

```
a <- c(0.11, 0.02, 0.01, 0.1, 0.08, 0.04, 0.02, 0.03) # Two years worth of returns
```

I would like to apply some function that outputs a vector of length 2 with yearly returns using the formula:

```
Year 1: ((1 + 0.11) * (1 + 0.02) * (1 + 0.01) * (1 + 0.1))-1  = 0,2578742
Year 2: ((1 + 0.08) * (1 + 0.04) * (1 + 0.02) * (1 + 0.03))-1 = 0,180033
```

Final vector:

```
yearly_vec <- c(0.2578742,  0.180033)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `apply`:

```
apply(matrix(a, nrow = 4), 2, function(x) prod(1 + x) - 1)
#[1] 0.2578742 0.180033
```

Comment: `apply(matrix(a+1, 4), 2, prod) - 1`

Comment: @jogo Such an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

As they are quarterly returns divide the vector into groups of 4 and calculate for each group.

```
tapply(a, gl(length(a)/4, 4), function(x) prod(1 + x) - 1)
#    1      2 
#0.2579 0.1800
```

The grouping part and calculation part can be done in variety of ways. For example, the above can also be done using `split` + `sapply`

```
sapply(split(a, gl(length(a)/4, 4)), function(x) prod(1 + x) - 1)
```

Or grouping can also be done using `rep`

```
tapply(a,rep(seq_along(a), each = 4, length.out = length(a)), 
         function(x) prod(1 + x) - 1)
```

Comment: `tapply(a+1, gl(length(a)/4, 4), prod) - 1`

Answer (score 1):

An option:

```
    c(by(a, rep(1:(length(a)/4), each = 4), FUN = function(x) 

  (1 + x[1]) * (1 + x[2]) * (1 + x[3]) * (1 + x[4])-1

  )
))

        1         2 
0.2578742 0.1800339
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) ts**  These are really intended to represent time series so it makes sense to use a time series representation:

```
aggregate(ts(1+a, freq = 4), 1, prod) - 1
## Time Series:
## Start = 1 
## End = 2 
## Frequency = 1 
[1] 0.2578742 0.1800339
```

We could also use the `start=` argument if knew the year that the series starts, e.g.

```
aggregate(ts(1+a, freq = 4, start = 2000), 1, prod) - 1
```

**2) rollapply**  This takes the product of every 4 values skipping ahead 4 each time (instead of a sliding window moving ahead by 1).

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(1 + a, 4, by = 4, prod) - 1
## [1] 0.2578742 0.1800339
```

**3) aggregate.zoo** Suppose we have a `yeaqqtr` vector `yq` that gives the year and quarter of each point.  `yearqtr` renders as shown below and internally is represented as year + fraction where the fraction is 0, 1/4, 2/4 and 3/4 for Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4.  Given that we can aggregate over it:

```
library(zoo)

yq <- as.yearqtr(2000) + 0:7/4
yq
## [1] "2000 Q1" "2000 Q2" "2000 Q3" "2000 Q4" "2001 Q1" "2001 Q2" "2001 Q3"
## [8] "2001 Q4"

aggregate(zoo(1 + a), as.integer(yq), prod) - 1
##      2000      2001 
## 0.2578742 0.1800339
```

**3a)**  Using the same `yq` we can `tapply` over `1+a` :

```
library(zoo)

tapply(1 + a, as.integer(yq), prod) - 1
##      2000      2001 
## 0.2578742 0.1800339
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea via base R,

```
sapply(split(a, rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each = length(a) / 2)), 
             function(i)((1 + i[1]) * (1 + i[2]) * (1 + i[3]) * (1 + i[4])) - 1)

#    FALSE      TRUE 
#0.2578742 0.1800339
```