# Convert quarterly returns to yearly returns from a matrix

Tags: r

Given a matrix of quarterly returns, with columns representing returns for different stocks, how can I apply a function that returns a new matrix with yearly returns?

As I am fairly new to R, I don't really know where to start to solve this problem.

```
# Quarterly returns for stock A and B 
a <- c(-0.2, 0.02, 0.06, 0.041)
b <- c(0.18, -0.04, 0.06, 0.07)
ab <- cbind(a,b)
```

Using this formula:

```
prod(1 + x) - 1
```

I need to output a matrix consisting of yearly returns for each stock.

I need a row entry for each year. So, if I have observed 8 quarters (2 years), the matrix will have 2 rows.

Comment: Put any one answer you got from this question in a function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323887/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-consecutive-n-elements-in-a-vector and then use `apply(ab, 2, function_name)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a function to every consecutive n elements in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323887/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-consecutive-n-elements-in-a-vector) It is the same calculation - now for two stocks, in the other question for two years.

Comment: @jogo, see edit

Comment: It be easier If you shared the expected output

Comment: `"have observed 8 quarters (2 years)"` - please provide representative data, and expected output.

Comment: You might want to split the data by years, then use `apply` solution from the links, i.e.: double loop.

Comment: For 8 quaters for each stock: `yret <- function(x) apply(matrix(1+x, nrow=4), 2, prod) - 1;
apply(ab, 2, yret)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
a <- c(-0.2, 0.02, 0.06, 0.041, 0.18, -0.04, 0.06, 0.07)
b <- c(0.18, -0.04, 0.06, 0.07, -0.2, 0.02, 0.06, 0.041)
ab <- cbind(a,b)

yret <- function(x) apply(matrix(1+x, nrow=4), 2, prod) - 1
apply(ab, 2, yret)
# > apply(ab, 2, yret)
#                a           b
# [1,] -0.09957664  0.28482176
# [2,]  0.28482176 -0.09957664
```

or as Roland commented:

```
apply(array(ab, c(4, nrow(ab)/4, ncol(ab))) + 1, 2:3, prod) - 1 # or
apply(array(ab+1, c(4, nrow(ab)/4, ncol(ab))), 2:3, prod) - 1
```

to conserve the names of the columns:

```
apply(array(ab+1, c(4, nrow(ab)/4, ncol(ab)), dimnames=list(NULL, NULL, colnames(ab))), 2:3, prod) - 1
```

Comment: `apply(array(ab, c(4, 2, 2)) + 1, 2:3, prod) - 1`

Answer (score -2):

apply(ab,2,function(x) prod(1 + x) - 1)